# Simple react todo app and storing todos in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a simple todo app that I am trying to get the 'todos' stored in firebase. Here are the relevant files...

## base.js

```
import Rebase from 're-base';
import Firebase from 'firebase';

const app = Firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "mykey",
    authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com",
});

const base = Rebase.createClass(app.database());

export default base;
```

## TodoList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoItems from './TodoItems';
import TodoInput from './TodoInput';
import base from './base';

class TodoList extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    todos: React.PropTypes.array
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { todos: this.props.todos || [] }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.ref = base.syncState({
      context: this,
      state: 'todos'
    });
  }

  addTodo = (item) => {
    this.setState({todos: this.state.todos.concat([item])});
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>TODO List</h3>
        <TodoItems items={this.state.todos}/>
        <TodoInput addTodo={this.addTodo}/>
      </div>
    );    
  }
};

export default TodoList;
```

The error I am getting is:

```
REBASE: The Firebase endpoint you are trying to listen to must be a string. Instead, got [object Object]
```

in `this.ref = base.syncState({`. I am dubious about the `this.ref` but am not sure what to put in its stead. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was having is that when calling `syncState` in `componentWillMount` I need to pass two arguments, the first being the a firebase endpoint. So the solution is below...not I added /todos as the first argument.

```
  componentWillMount(){
    this.ref = base.syncState('/todos', {
      context: this,
      state: 'todos'
    });
  }
```